# Mostrando e ocultando input

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um botão, quando clicar nele quero que apareça um campo do tipo `input`, nesse campo, quando eu adicionar algum texto quero que o mesmo vá para o banco de dados, com um `ALTER table`. Como fazer o `input` aparecer e como fazê-lo sumir?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) pra fazer isso sem muito esforço:

No html inicie o seu `input` como oculto.

```
<input type="text" id="seu-input" style="display:none">
```

Crie um botão para exibir o `input`:

```
<button id="exibe-input">Meu botão</button>
```

E por último crie uma função javascript para que quando o botão for clicado exiba o campo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#exibe-input').click(function(){
 $('#seu-input').css("display", "block");  
}
</script>
```

Para ocultar o campo pode ser criada outra função com a ação contrária.

```
$('#seu-input').css("display", "none");
```

---

Fonte: [The display property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Amigo, dependendo da versão do Jquery, ele não vai aceitar .css( 'propriedade' : valor ), você terá que passar os valores CSS como objeto, exemplo: .css({ 'display' : 'none'}).
É só uma observação.